# Magento forwarding not to point 4

Tags: magento-1.8, error, payment, shopping-cart, shipping-methods

I have a big problem. When one person will buy in my online shop. All work but after select the shipping, and klick on forth, they not forwarding to point 4 the payment method.

That only remains on point 3.

Please help me.

Comment: Any custom extension used related to checkout?

Comment: I dont now what you mean but I send you a link of my homepage where you can look. http://www.schücobeschläge.com

Comment: Please read these answers: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store and add more details.